# snowflake stored proc using parameter

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

i need to create stored proc using javascript with parameters.

```
create or replace sp_test(name staring  , flag varchar, loaddate datetime)
returns varchar
language javascript
execute as CALLER
as
'
var sql_comm1;

sql_comm1 = '
if(flag == ''i'')

    insert into test1
    (name,
     date)

    select 
    name, -- this should be parameter values
    date -- this should be parameter values

    ';

 snowflake.execute({sqlText.sql : sql_comm1)
 ;
```

I am getting errors in the IF statement, also how will I use the parameter here?

Comment: The code in a javascript IF statement needs to be surrounded by {}. What are you trying to do with the parameters!

Comment: so if flag = 'i' i need to insert record , it 'U' then i need to update the record here . what is correct syntax

Comment: You use an IF…THEN…ELSE structure

Answer (score 0):

The template for such a stored procedure could look like this:

```
create or replace sp_test(name staring, flag varchar, loaddate datetime)
returns varchar
language javascript
execute as CALLER
as
$$
var sql_comm1;
if (flag == 'i') {
    sql_comm1 = `insert into test1 (name, date) select` + NAME + `,` + DATE + ` from <some_table>`;
} else if (flag == 'u') {
    sql_comm1 = `update test1 ....`;
}

 snowflake.execute({sqlText.sql : sql_comm1)
 
$$
;
```

Be aware of the case-sensitivity in JavaScript arguments as documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-javascript#case-sensitivity-in-javascript-arguments).